# Any Juggernaut alternative for GWT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gwt, atmosphere, server-push, juggernaut

Is it possible to use `Juggernaut` with `GWT` or does anyone know of an engine for GWT that provides realtime server connection like Juggernaut for Rails?

Comment: I have used this extensions: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-extensions/tree/master/gwt20/modules

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Is Atmosphere runs on a separate port like Juggernaut? I tried with JBoss Errai it works well but does not run independently, it will run on the server side and push messages to the client.